# problem in dimensionality reduction

Tags: computational-geometry, data-analysis, triangulation

I am using multidimensional scaling to plot my data in R. However there is a hierarchy in my dataset which i want to exploit and I am using the delaunay triangulation to visualize the plot. So now I have plotted the triangulation for the parent level. Now I want to plot the subsequent levels in each parent tile. Is there a way in which I can input the parent tile boundaries as the boundaries for my next triangulation?

How do I scale the distance between the points which i obtain from multidimensional scaling such that all the points are inside its parent tile?